# How does a compiler remember declared variable when used in expression?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, semantics

How does a compiler keep track of the declaration of a variable when it is used in an expression?

For example, if I have the following code:

```
int num = 1; //declaration
num = 2; //expression
```

I know that the syntax tree will generate a branch for the declaration and a branch for the expression but how does it maintain the connection between them in the semantic analyzer?

Comment: The best way to learn such things (IMO) is to try to make your *own* compiler (for some simple language). It's fun, and you'll learn a lot (besides how symbols and variables are passed between different parts of the compiler).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler's semantic analysis phase includes dealing with a *symbol table*, which, as the name implies, keeps track of all the symbols (names) used in the program. This also allows to detect undeclared names, for example.

So, when the analyzer "sees" a declaration, it creates a new symbol (like `Symbol(type=Int, offset=0)`) and inserts it into a map `name -> Symbol`. For example, `symbol_table["num"] = Symbol(type=Int, offset=0)`.

Then, when analyzing an expression or a statement (it's a statement in your example), the compiler can, for example, analyze the types of its members. To do this, it looks up the names used in the symbol table:

```
assign_to_symbol = symbol_table["num"]
if assign_to_symbol.type == right_hand_side.type:
    DoStuff()
else:
    ThatIsAnError()
```

If there's no name `"num"` in this scope, the lookup fails, thus signaling an error.

Comment: would symbol table be a hash map? or would it be a stack? and would it deal with the appropriate scope as well?

Comment: Well, can a stack be indexed with strings? It can't, but a hash map can. Whether it keeps track of scope depends on the implementation and the specification of your language. Given appropriate semantic actions, you can certainly make it do this.

Comment: It's just an example of information a symbol can hold. In this case, it's the offset from the beginning of the current stack frame. This makes it possible to allocate memory for data local to functions.